# About compatible version of .Net framework to My desktop app

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I am using .Net framework 4.5 for my desktop app, Can the user install .Net framework 4.5.1 on his device and my app works good or he must install 4.5 version
Thanks

Comment: They can have any currently available version later than .NET Framework 4.5. The problems occur when your application uses later version that it is installed on the user's machine. It should be Framework, not Core though, otherwise use .NET Standard.

Comment: The official article is here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .NET Framework versions are backwards-compatible within the same major version number: so a .NET Framework 4.7.2 installation can run a program built for .NET Framework 4.0, 4.5, 4.6, etc - there is also a limited amount of major-version backwards compatibility where a .NET Framework 4.x installation can run programs built for .NET Framework 2.0 or even .NET Framework 1.1. Note this does not apply to .NET Core.

Comment: BTW, `dnx` is an obsolete term and is not standardized for .NET Core any more.